Trouble With MATLAB Variable Creation
I would like to dynamically read in data and assign data values from a text file.
Here is the text file:
object crop_image.nii
plane 3
coeff -5.046e-19 3.168e-13 -5.716e-8 0.005 2.746
amax 1
nfact 1
pt .9906
suvr 1
regi 1

Initially, I was reading it in using this block of code (which works).
readin = readlines(insert text file name here);

for i = 1:length(readin)
    this = split(readin(i))';

    switch this(1)
        case 'object'
            object = this{2};
        case 'plane'
            plane = str2double(this{2});
        case 'coeff'
            coeff = str2double(this(2:end));
        case 'suvr'
            suvr = str2double(this{2});
        case 'amax'
            amax = str2double(this{2});
        case 'nfact'
            nfact = str2double(this{2});
        case 'pt'
            pt = str2double(this{2});
        case 'regi'
            regi = str2double(this{2});
        otherwise
            fprintf('Invalid delimiter: %s! Please check your text file.\n', this{1});
            return;
    end
end

But a huge switch case doesn't really give polish. I guess it shouldn't matter if the code works, but still. I'd like it to be more refined.
Oh, yeah, the reason for all the cell array stuff (and for the huge switch case) is because I'll be running this code (this code is a portion of a much larger script) from Linux. Also, the text file isn't guaranteed to come in the order of object, plane, coeff, etc., which is why I have the code detect the first word.
Anyway, I thought I could solve my issue using the assignin function, but it's not working? Here's what I have so far.
if ismember(this(1), ["object", "plane", "coeff", "suvr", "amax", "nfact", "pt", "regi"])
    if isa(this(2), 'string') 
        assignin('base', this(1), this(2));
    else
        assignin('base', this(1), str2double(this(2:end)));
    end
else
    fprintf('Invalid delimiter: %s! Please check your text file.\n', this(1));
    return;
end

I've done my best to debug. The code is not skipping over the assignin function. That line of code is executing, but when it executes, nothing happens.
Like, I've checked the values of this(1) and this(2) right before the script calls the assignin function. Yes, this(1) equals "object" and this(2) equals the object name, also a string, but nothing shows up when the assignin line of code executes. I don't get it. Would appreciate any and all suggestions. Thanks.

@CrisLuengo sorry, "this" is a string array.

@Cris curly braces with strings return the "internal" char array. If s=["ab","c"]; then s{1}='ab'

The variables are saved in base workspace. I'm not sure if you're using this code inside another code, is there probably another higher-level function that sets the base workspace?

You should avoid eval where possible, as well as dynamic variable names. Using dynamic field names in structures is generally preferred and syntactically simpler. In this example I've grouped all of your outputs under the structure out, which can be accessed like out.coeff.
You shouldn't need the big switch because you're treating everything the same (converting to double) unless it's an object line, so you can handle that as a special case.
I've added comments to the code below to explain each step:
readin = readlines('temp.txt');

% Initialise output struct
out = struct();

% Loop over file - one string per line
for i = 1:length(readin)
    % Split on spaces
    this = split(readin(i))';

    % Extract the name and value(s) from the line
    name = this(1);
    val = this(2:end);

    if ~strcmp( name, 'object' )
        % Unless this is object name, treat the value as a double
        % It doesn't matter if it's scalar or array
        val = str2double(val);
    end

    % Assign to output struct
    out.(name) = val;
end

Result:


Since this is all string arrays, you might as    we do if name == "object".
